# Calculating the cumulative bottom values for a stacked bar chart when the length of the array varies

Tags: python, matplotlib, yahoo-finance, trading

Found how to do it:
used pandas to groupby strike,expiration and sum openInterest, then after a couple of hours of scratching my head i learned what .unstack() does and did that.

```
y = option_chain.groupby(['strike', 'expirationDate'])['openInterest'].sum().unstack(level=-1)
y.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

I am looking to plot a stacked bar chart for options open interest. I am looking to do the exact same thing as the person in this link : https://medium.com/@txlian13/webscraping-options-data-with-python-and-yfinance-e4deb0124613 . I have the data from the same source and I have it arranged in the same way.

My problem is that I can't find a way to calculate the bottom argument and chart looks like this:
[image]
all the values start at y=0 and not the previous bar height

tried this code among other options but not managed to make it work

exp is a list of all possible expiration dates for the options

```py
bottom = np.zeros(12) #(using 12 because I am testing with the same stock, so I know my first array needs to be 12 to match the number of strikes for the first date)
for i in exp:
    z = option_chain.loc[option_chain['expirationDate'] == i]
    zx = z['strike']
    zy = z['openInterest']
    #here i print my bottom and its an empty array of 0s so it will plot the next line from 0
    plt.bar(zx,zy,label=i,alpha=0.7,bottom=bottom)
    bottom += zy
    #i print bottom again here and I can see that it has the 12 correct values of the open interest
    #then i get an error "ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape"
```

So my problem is that the strike (my x values) changes with every iteration I make. For example my first iteration has 12 values for x and the second one has 9 value for x.

So, is there a way to have a variable array that changes with my x and also I realize this will lead to another problem: how to match the x's so that it gets added to the correct strike.

One way I was thinking to do is to find which date has the most strikes and use that as my base, but the problem with that is that it is not given that the date with most strikes has all the strikes in the other dates.

If the problem can be easily fixed with another plotting package, I have no issue in using that. I am a finance graduate and just trying to learn python so only used matplotlib as it's the one the with the most learning materials out there.

Comment: Maybe [plot.bar(stacked=True)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) can help.

Comment: matplotlib has not kwargs "stacked" unfortunately. I think that's from pandas and I did try to plot using that but didn't manage to make it work

Comment: That's a pandas thing, not matplotlib. See the link.

Comment: if I use that inside the loop i get as many plots as I have iterations. They don't get added on to the same plot. Any way to solve that?

Comment: tried doing this : y = option_chain.groupby(['strike','expirationDate'])['openInterest'].sum(). but this plots all the expiration dates and strikes as individual xs